# Rsync always failing at the same point

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, nfs, windows-server

I made a script for my Proxmox host to make a copy of its daily backups to another machine (running Windows Server 2022).

The script mounts a NFS share from the Windows host and runs this rsync command:

```
rsync -ahzP --stats --update --delete-before --delete-excluded --exclude "*.log" /mnt/raid/ /mnt/backups > /root/ext_backup.log
```

It runs for about 30 minutes and then it throws this error:

```
rsync: [receiver] write failed on "/mnt/backups/backups/dump/vzdump-qemu-101-2022_01_23-00_00_01.vma.zst": Input/output error (5)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(378) [receiver=3.2.3]

rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

What could be the problem?

*On the windows machine there's all the needed space for the backup operation and the file it's not corrupted.*

Comment: Can you also provide the command line you use to mount the share?

Comment: @ZivkoK Sure, here it is: `mount -t nfs 192.168.1.105:/pve-backups /mnt/backups`

Comment: Does it always fail at the same file (vzdump-qemu-101-2022_01_23-00_00_01.vma.zst) or is it random? If random, were you able to identify a common pattern? (large files or files in use)

Comment: @ZivkoK it fails after about 30 minutes regardless of what file is transfering (if I remove that file, it will crash on the next one).

Comment: Can you try adding a timeout option to rsync command (i.e --timeout=60) to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @ZivkoK Yes, I'll let the script run tonight so I will update you on this tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: @ZivkoK Ok so, nothing changed.

Comment: My last though will be a problem on the target disk. Did you run a check disk on the Windows target disk?

Comment: @ZivkoK do you mean the `chkdsk` command?

Comment: Yes at least. I you have another way to do it (HD vendor tools or something like Seagate SeaTools, HDDScan, etc.), it's even better. Sometimes, chkdsk is not capable of finding HD problems (both physical or digital).

Comment: @ZivkoK I've tried with chkdsk and no errors were found. To be 100% sure, I'll try other tools.

Comment: @ZivkoK I ran HDDScan on all my disks and it seems that everything is alright.

Comment: Sorry not being able to help... what I would personally do in this case is a return to basics: Try to perform the backup on a local drive (i.e. USB HD) to see if this works. If successful, the problem must be linked to the backup destination (nfs share). If not, the problem must be linked to the backup source or command used.

Comment: @ZivkoK No problems, thanks anyway for all the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### How I solved it:

I've discovered [this forgotten post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=268240) on the ArchLinux forum, and tried the solution:

It seemed to be a cache problem or something related.

**To have it working, I just added `-o fg,noac,lookupcache=none` to the `mount` command.**